# Please help me translate what is carved on my dizi flute. Thank you!

Tags: translation

I tried handwriting it in Google translate, but struggle to copy the characters. Please, help me! Thank you very much in advance!!

http://s019.radikal.ru/i635/1511/0e/38a93e447481.jpg

Comment: I think that translations of non-Mandarin literature ought not to be considered off-topic. They're usually too difficult for machine translation to handle, and there is an element of skill involved well beyond what would be necessary for ordinary working Mandarin.

Answer (score 5):

六出飛花入戶時，坐看青竹變瓊枝。

A Tang poem (对雪) by 高骈 (Gao Pian), with the following meaning: Snow flakes are falling on the bamboo poles of the house, and I am sitting here watching the landscape turn white.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! What a beautiful poem! I couldn't have translated it without your help. You are very kind. Thank you!!

Comment: @Julia in case you want the full poem: `《对雪》：六出飛花入戶時，坐看青竹變瓊枝。
如今好上高樓望，蓋盡人間惡路歧。`

Answer (score 2):

```
Flying "flowers" of snow, each jutting sixfold — 
    as these enter our home,
we sit watching the green bamboo
    turning to trees of pale jade.
```

The square text on the bottom says "國韻製造 [manufactured by Guóyùn 'national in-tune']".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! Your expertise is greatly appreciated.